# Can't connect real phones with connection code (AirConsole, Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

Im developing a game for AirConsole in Unity and i am having issues with testing it on my phone.

Everything works as expected when running the game with airconsole Browser start mode: Virtual Controllers, EXCEPT connecting with my real phone.
[The virtual controllers view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m88PK.png)

Connecting real phones is not available through the AirConsole app so i have to use a browser.
The issue is that with my (Samsung) phone i can't connect to the game because it redirects me instantly to the "Download App" screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buvSd.jpg)

This same problem is also ocurring with any of the provided AirConsole examples such a the pong example.

When i tested it with my friends who have iPhones and used Safari, they were able to connect succesfully. I have tried 4 different browsers on my samsung phone with no luck.

Also when i go to http://192.168.3.10:7842/controller.html on my phone, it loads the controllers no problem. (I am for sure on the same WiFi and there is no problem with client separation)
I also tried using ngrok and there was no difference.. as it seems the problem is with the forced rederect and not the actual connections.

When i checked the network calls by remotely debugging the phones browser i get this call sequence:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVd21.png)
This is the stuff that loads right after when i press the green checkmark button after inputing the connection code.. Then this all dissapears when the ?http=1 is loaded and then i am redirected to the download app screen again.

Another thing that might be connected with this issue is that when i start the game with AirConsole Browser Start Mode: Normal/Debug, i get CONNECTION_REFUSED in the browser.

I am developing on a M1 Mac and using AirConsole unity plugin v2.13 and Unity 2021.3.24f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out :)

I am actually preparing a new releases that addresses this and the related bug (https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/issues/8).
The release is expected to go live tomorrow (Nov 2nd, 2023) with the Unity AssetStore release as soon after as their review process allows for.

You can visit our discord at https://discord.gg/8tQgS2ZJ to be kept up to date or revisit https://github.com/airconsole/airconsole-unity-plugin later this week

Comment: Hi @Marc Schärer  and thank you for the quick response and package update, but unfortunately my problem persists.

Here is the video showing my exact problem:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/OwNkl8V)

If i was to guess the problem lies with the AirConsole website but i am not sure.
Note that when i connect to AirConsole hub through the phone browser it connects succesfully so the problem is only when connecting to my own game in unity.

Comment: I have tried using the cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:7842 like it shows in the documentation and i got it working.. But there is no reason why it should not work without it as i am on my own local wifi with no firewalls or anything.. but i guess this will do for now

Comment: It depends on the game. Depending on that you might or might not be impacted.

If your game requires access to the sensors (gyroscope for example), you need to be on HTTPS. This is a browser security requirement.
Originally airconsole.com on https did the trick but since summer 2023, browsers will treat any connection that has a HTTP part involved as insecure, no matter if it is part of the page or the iframe (your controller / screen)

If you need the AirConsole controller app, you must be on HTTPS. Mobile Security practices require us to open the browser controller otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've been made aware that while the access with physical controller to Unity works in normal / debug mode, there are still cases with the simulator where this constellation is facing issues.
I've tried to replicate them with v2.14 but I fail to do so with Virtual Controllers and the Local IP Override.

Without the Local IP Override, there are potential issues because all security related APIs are by default rejected on http connections (gyro, NoSleep, etc).

If you currently are experiencing this, could you reach out to me (dreamora_ch on the discord server or here)? I would appreciate that.